# Getting TypeError while performing operation on tensorflow objects

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-slim

Below is the simplified version of the code, I am getting error at line `res = input - var`

```
import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 150, 220, 3], name='x')

input = slim.conv2d(x,  num_outputs=96, kernel_size=11, stride=4, padding=padding, scope=scope, weights_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01), biases_initializer=None, activation_fn=None)

var = tf.zeros_initializer()

res = input - var
```

**Variable types**

```
input type: <tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops.Zeros object at 0x7f1a017fdb38>
var_type: Tensor("conv1/Conv2D:0", shape=(?, 35, 53, 96), dtype=float32)
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: Expected float32, got <tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops.Zeros object at 0x7f1a017fdb38> of type 'Zeros' instead.
```

How can I solve it, any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this rows you are trying to substract a method from a tensor.

```
var = tf.zeros_initializer()
res = input - var
```

Comment: small typo I have fixed the post

Comment: i have fixed the answer